# Angular - CSS - custom type=file input, how to use a button instead of label?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, input

I made a custom input field of type="file" as I didn't like the default one.
To achieve this I did:

```
<input
            #uploadFile
            type="file"
            id="uploadFile"
            class="hidden-input"
            accept="image/jpeg, .jpeg, image/png, .png, image/pjpeg, .jpg, .docx, .pdf"
            (change)="selectFile($event.target.files[0])"
        />

     <label [matTooltip]="Upload a file" for="uploadFile">
<mat-icon>folder_open</mat-icon>
</label>
```

so basically it hides the original input, and with the  tag I can open the browse file window by clicking on the mat-icon.

This works well, but instead of label I wanted to use the tag `<button mat-icon-button>` to have a nice ripple effect on the icon, but the `"for"` used in the label doesn't work for `<button>`.

If I wrap my `mat-icon` inside the label tag with the above button tag, what would happen is, the `button` looks how I want it, but when I click nothing happens, I suppose it's because the `button` is above the `label`, so the `label` doesn't get the click, I tried using `z-index` but wouldn't work.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just make a button whose click fires a click event on the hidden file input

```
<button (click)="uploadFile.click()" mat-icon-button>
 <mat-icon>arrow_upward</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: for my case this is the best answer, I didn't know you could fire click events for other html elements like that! The above answers might take a deeper and more complete approach, but for my case this is the correct answer! thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
.label{
      padding: 10px;
      color: #fff;
    }



    input[type="file"] {
        display: none;
    }

    .label-input{
      font: bold 13px Arial;
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: #2387aa;
      color: #EEEEEE;
      padding: 4px 79px 5px 66px;
      border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
      /* border-right: 1px solid #333333; */
      /* border-bottom: 1px solid #333333; */
      border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    }


 <label class="label-input"> Upload file
                    <input type="file" id="File">
                </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this link to your `index.html`

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

To your `app.module` add 
`MatIconModule`

in Html:

```
<input #uploadFile
            type="file"
            id="uploadFile"
            class="hidden-input"
            accept="image/jpeg, .jpeg, image/png, .png, image/pjpeg, .jpg, .docx, .pdf"
            />

<button for="uploadFile" (click)="selectFile()">
<mat-icon>folder_open</mat-icon>
</button>
```

In ts make `onchange` function:

```
 files: Array<any> = [];

  selectFile() {
    const fileUpload = document.getElementById('uploadFile') as HTMLInputElement;
    fileUpload.onchange = () => {
      for (let index = 0; index < fileUpload.files.length; index++) {
        const file = fileUpload.files[index];
        this.files.push(data: file);
      }
    };
    fileUpload.click();
  }
```