# How call a click event on an input element with Angular

Tags: angular, html

I'm trying to make an upload button because I don't want to use the HTML upload button, how can I call a click event on the input element to open the file browser manually?

```
<div class="upload-button button" (click)="selectFile()">
   Upload
   <input type="file">
</div>
```

Comment: See this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53813791/angular-css-custom-type-file-input-how-to-use-a-button-instead-of-label/53813912#53813912

Answer (score 5):

I would do it with the # decorator in the view. This way we can give the input a name and just call name.click() to call it from a button for example:

```
<button (click)="fileSelect.click()">Click me for fun!</button>
<input style="display: none" #fileSelect type="file">
```

The # according to docs: "Creates a local variable that provides access to the element instance in data-binding and event-binding expressions in the current template." [Cheatsheet](https://angular.io/guide/cheatsheet)

Answer (score 3):

Just click will make it work as per my understanding:

```html
<div class="upload-button button" (click)="file.click()">
  Upload
  <input type="file" #file>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: No, if you click on the text Upload it will not open the file chooser. click="file" means nothing.

Comment: @LajosArpad , Thanks for your comment. I have updated the code snippet as per my understanding.

Comment: This is still not correct. file does not mean anything in that context. You will just need to find the input, possibly by id, see my answer.

Comment: @LajosArpad, okay. Thanks again.

Comment: @stol has explained it correctly in the answer above.